# How to get image dimensions using a string url

Tags: android, imageview

I am working on an android app. I want to show images and want to check the width and height of that image.
I am having url of Image https://dptw5wbct4ot.cloudfront.net/public/album_photo/64/23/01/12142_23eb.jpg?c=6cbc and want to get the width and height from this url of image, so that I can calculate the height and width of the imageview accordingly.

Do anyone have any idea here, please help.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Comment: Do you need to calculate the size before, in order to download it then? Otherwise, you could just download image, and call getWidth() and getHeight() methods to calculate size.

Comment: I need to calculate the size before because I need the image width and height to set on imageview.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://dptw5wbct4ot.cloudfront.net/public/album_photo/64/23/01/12142_23eb.jpg?c=6cbc"));
            int width = image.getWidth(null);
            int height = image.getHeight(null);
            System.out.println(width + "x" + height);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Note that I use awt package.

Comment: I cannot import java.awt* package in my application.

Comment: I have found the below solution 

`InputStream in = new java.net.URL(mainImage).openStream();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);`

But I need to run it inside onBindViewHolder of Recyclerview Adapter and it is giving me the below error 
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

How can I do this then ?

Comment: @PrithnirajNicyone use SwingWorker.